# What is the difference between defining method in class and implementing interface and overriding its method in android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have to show SnackBar message in whole app where needed, for this I had made a class named as "CSnackBar" and defined Snackbar implementation and calling this method in activity where needed.My question is that is this correct way by memory point of view or I can define that one using interface instead, If yes then how and what this will effect app smoothness.

code for "CSnackBar" class

```
private static CSnackBar s_m_oCSnackBar;// declare snack bar variable

public static CSnackBar getInstance() {// creating Instance of nack bar
    if (s_m_oCSnackBar == null) {
        s_m_oCSnackBar = new CSnackBar();
    }
    return s_m_oCSnackBar;
}

public void showSnackBarError(View v, String message, Context context) {// parametrised constructor

    Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(v, "" + message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    View view = snack.getView();
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    else
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    ColoredSnackbar.alert(snack).show();
}

public void showSnackBarSuccess(View v, String message, Context context) {

    Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(v, "" + message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    View view = snack.getView();
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    else
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    ColoredSnackbar.confirm(snack).show();
}
```

and I am calling Snack bar like this in activity where I need to show Snackbar message.

```
CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, "Invalid Password", getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a singletone class for this, meaning that your snackbar instance will be on memory always after creating it. Also see that you are not accessing to any property of the instance inside your methods, so I find it unnecessary.
What I would do is to make showSnackBarError and showSnackBarSuccess static (with a bit of refactoring):

```
public static void showSnackBarError(View v, String message, Context context) {
    Snackbar snack = initSnackBar();
    ColoredSnackbar.alert(snack).show();
}

public static void showSnackBarSuccess(View v, String message, Context context) {
    Snackbar snack = initSnackBar();
    ColoredSnackbar.confirm(snack).show();
}

private initSnackBar(View v, String message, Context context){
    Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(v, "" + message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    View view = snack.getView();
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    } else {
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    }
}
```

And then calling them as:

```
CSnackBar.showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, "Invalid Password", getApplicationContext());
```

About defining an interface and the overriding it with those methods, I will use it if you create a class that extends Snackbar, something like

```
interface SnackbarInterface{
   showSnackBarError(View v, String message, Context context);
   showSnackBarSuccess(View v, String message, Context context )
}

class CSnackBar extends SnackBar implements SnackBarInterface{

   CSnackBar();

   @Override
   showSnackBarError(View v, String message, Context context){
   ...
   }

   @Override
   showSnackBarSuccess(View v, String message, Context context ){
   ...
   }
```

The diference is that in that way, you are creating a custom snackbar, so you should modify its properties instead of creating a Snackbar object. As I see you are using the default Snackbar provided, I guess its not appealing to you to use it in this way.

The other option I see with interfaces in the way you are showing the snackbar is that your activities extends a custom class that implements that interface so they would have the showSnackBarError and showSnackBarSuccess inherited. However, I see the best way to proceed will be the first one.

Hope I answered your answer instead of confusing you more :/

Comment: which one is better in terms of memory

Comment: Both of the above will be the same. Think the first one adjust more to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are used to get callbacks from another class or activity to fetch data.
As of my knowledge you are doing right with creating a class and making some methods in it that will be fine. pardon me for my english.